# Github autologin through web

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have a private git repo for a test project, and I want some people to test it out. But getting them to submit comments/errors they have is hard since they are not really computer users who want to signup for a git account.

Thus, I want to login to git with a fixed user/pass that I would create through a web interface, hiding the login details from the user (hiding as in without them having to worry about creating an acct), and then forwarding them to the git project page.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible if you use the [basic authentication](http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) of the Github API. Of course you have to remember that all those users will share the same [rate limit](http://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) (5000 requests per hour).

Remembering this, everything else the API gives you for this hidden account should be possible.